# Returning other lines using readline

Tags: ruby

I am reading a file using the following code:

```
f = File.open(file_path)
f.readline
```

This reads the first line of the file. Is it possible to return the second or the fifth line?

Comment: Don't forget to close your file afterwards or better yet: use the block form `File.open(filename) { |file| ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep doing it as many times as the line number.

```
f = File.open(file_path)
l = nil
5.times{l = f.readline}
l # => fifth line
```

Comment: I like your one... no extra iteration needed.. :-) +1

Comment: note that `readline` raises an `EOFError` when reaching the end of file

Answer (score 1):

You can keep calling `f.readline` until you get an `EOFError`. Each subsequent call will read a new line.

You can also use `f.readlines`

```
lines = f.readlines
```

Answer (score 1):

[`IO#each`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/IO.html#method-i-each) returns a line enumerator, [`Enumerable#take`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-take) returns the first n elements (i.e. lines) as an array and [`Array#last`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-last) returns its last element, i.e. the nth line:

```
File.open(file_path) do |f|
  line_5 = f.each.take(5).last
end
```

Or using [`IO::foreach`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/IO.html#method-c-foreach):

```
line_5 = IO.foreach(file_path).take(5).last
```

Note that this will return the file's last line if your file has less than five lines. Alternatively, you could use [`Array#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) which returns `nil` in that case:

```
line_5 = IO.foreach(file_path).take(5)[5] # 5th line or nil
```